# What is the best practice to sent a text message to your self from Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sms, sendmail

First of all, I'm not entirely if this is event possible to do.
I'm trying to send a tiny information from my laravel application to my phone via **text message**.

I want to send the information to a T-Mobile phone sample : `+19786770001`

```
<?php

$ip = trim(shell_exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"));

$text = Mail::send('emails.site_visit', array('ip' => $ip ) ,
      function ($ip) {
          $ip->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME') , 'sample gmail');
          $ip->to(env('+19786770001') , 'Sample\'s Site ')->subject(' Site Visit Report ' );
      });

?>
```

---

[image]

In order for me to see my content, I have to click on the `Attachment.html`.

- How comes I keep seeing `Attachement.html` ?
- How do I show the content in the text message rather than the html file ?
- What is the proper way of doing it ? Is it even possible ?

Any hints / suggestions on that will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the subject (because SMS doesn't use it) and also try sending it as plain text.

```
Mail::send(['text' => 'emails.site_visit'], array('ip' => $ip ), function ($ip) {
    $ip->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME');
    $ip->to('<PHONE_NUMBER>@tmomail.net');
});
```

Comment: Okay. I will try that now. Thank-you.

Comment: in my `site_visit.blade.php` only contain  `{{$ip}}` which is a plan text of an ip_addess.

Comment: I think, you're close. The message is gone because I took it off as you suggested, but in my text message app, I still see `Attachment.html` . :(

Comment: The item returned by `env('+19786770001') `  is a valid phone number followed by `@tmomail.net`?

Comment: I'm sure mine is `TMobile` - I just don't want to give it to the public . But the one that I posted, I'm not sure. Why ?

Comment: Your phone number isn't required, the important part is having the `@tmomail.net` at the end of it.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: `@tomail.net` is legit. Otherwise, I wouldn't get my text at all. I'm not sure if I am answering your question.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure it was actually a text and not an email being picked up by your texting app somehow.  Other then that, my only other ideas are to remove the extra stuff which would not be required by SMS such as the names.

Comment: remove the extra stuff ? Can you please be specific on what I should remove ?

Comment: The additional parameters in the `to` and `from` functions so that it looks similar to the answer I've modified..

Comment: Removing it as you suggested, still get that stupid `Attachment.html`